# Disable Hover Effect only on Touch Devices

Tags: jquery, ipad, hover, smartphone

My problem is the following: On my local website my main menu has an hover effect (border bottom). As we know it takes a double tap for visitors with touch devices to really tap the link. Is there a chance to disable the hover effect only on touch devices?

I've already tried the following:

```
$('a').on('click touchend', function(e) {
  var el = $(this);
  var link = el.attr('href');
  window.location = link;});
```

In fact that works well. I don't need to double tap the link, it works fine BUT on my desktop pc all normal `target="_blank"` links load in an extra tab (as usual) but also in the same tab. So the external links open twice. Is there a chance to avoid that?

I hope you understand what I mean.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: put a comma between click and touchend

Comment: errrm... The correct way of separating multiple events in jQuery's .on() is with spaces, not commas. I guess the only reason it works is that the "click" event is not needed in the first place and no listener is added for it because "click," is not a valid event type. Just removing the click altogether and leaving on('touchend', ... should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, just leave out the "click". Of course your desktop browser listens on the click event and thus will execute the handler.

```
$('a').on('touchend', function(e) {
var el = $(this);
var link = el.attr('href');
window.location = link;});
```

If you want to open links with target="_blank" in a new tab on mobile devices as well, you should account for that, check for the target and use window.open() in that case instead of window.location.

Please also keep in mind that nowadays there are desktop PCs with touch-enabled displays that will also listen to the "touchend" event and will open the links twice. So it would be a good idea to check if it's really necessary to open the links at second click instead of first click in the first place.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't unterstand :/ I did what you said and now it works on both (pc and iPad). But what did you mean with the touch pcs? Right now the target="_blank" links only open in a new tab - that's the way I wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

Oh... I tested it again with both methods. Now the PC version works fine but the iPad version doesn't (opens a new tab and load also in the same one). So it's just the other way round with those methods :/